# Definition of an isogeny of elliptic curves

Tags: algebraic-geometry, elliptic-curves, arithmetic-geometry, isogeny

If we define an isogeny between elliptic curves as a group homomorphism between elliptic curves given by rational polynomial coordinates, what problems arise?

Isogeny is usually defined as a morphism (in the context of algebraic geometry), but I have never encountered a situation in which the definition using rational polynomials is inappropriate.

Comment: Your definition is incorrect: you want an isogeny to be a finite map (i.e. a non-constant morphism).

Comment: If we add the condition $\phi(O)=O$, is the definition still incorrect ?

Comment: Is then $\phi$ defined to be the constant map $O$ an "isogeny"?

Comment: @dan_fulea. Silverman's book 'the arithmetic of elliptic curves' call it 'zero isogeny'. I don't feel the need to exclude zero isogeny. Where did I go wrong ?

Comment: @dan_fulea It is the zero isogeny,constant map.

Comment: Isogenies are given by rational polynomial functions that are "regular everywhere" on an elliptic curve.If you add the restriction that isogenies fix $O$,then they are automatically group homomorphisms.